# openlayers interaction only on left mouse

Tags: openlayers, context-menu, draw-interaction

Using openlayers (latest - 4), I have a drawing interaction that draws a circle -

```
let drawCircle = new ol.interaction.Draw({source: source, type: "Circle"});
map.addInteraction(drawCircle);
```

Both left mouse and right mouse click have the same behavior with this interaction- they start and stop the drawing of the circle.

I also have a context menu, so I do not want the right click to do anything with the interaction, just the left click.

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `condition` option for `ol.interaction.Draw`.
when condition meets, drawing will be started.

In your case, drawing should be start with leftclick(which means button code `1`)
So, simply add this code into `ol.interaction.Draw`'s option.

```
condition: function(e) {
  // when the point's button is 1(leftclick), allows drawing
  if (e.pointerEvent.buttons === 1) { 
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRmJYb

Comment: This is correct, but I found out we're using ol3-google-maps which is a custom build of openlayers 4.6.4 that for some reason sends different parameters to the condition function!

Comment: Then could you add your code with codepen or fiddle using ol3-google-maps? so I can try to figure out how.

Comment: In the minified version pointerEvent is not included as its not considered public api, so I had to use this instead: (e.originalEvent.buttons === 1)

Comment: You can simplify this with `return e.pointerEvent.buttons === 1` or in ES6 `condition: (e) => e.pointerEvent.buttons === 1`

Comment: Just want to point out that there is a `e.pointerEvent.buttons` and a `e.pointerEvent.button` not sure the exact difference but they have different mappings

Answer (score 0):

For OpenLayers 7.1.0 the condition is the folowing:

```
condition: (e) => e.originalEvent.buttons === 1
```

Answer (score 0):

And even higher OL

```
condition: (e) => {
          const pointerEvent = e.activePointers[0];
          if (pointerEvent.buttons === 1) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        },
```