# How to get long tap, right click or such events on OpenLayers5?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to get some pointer events like

- long tap
- right click

Are there any examples or documentations for archive them?

Comment: for right click, see this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276665/openlayers-interaction-only-on-left-mouse) and the valuable comments. Choose a value of "2" for right clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by myself for long tap:

```
var longpress = false;
map.on("click",function(e){
    (longpress) ? alert("Long Press") : alert("Short Press");
    console.log(map.getEventCoordinate(e.pixel));
});
var startTime, endTime;
map.on('pointerdown', function () {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
});
map.on('pointerup', function () {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(endTime - startTime);
    longpress = (endTime - startTime < 500) ? false : true;
});
```

Comment: in the latest version of openlayers 7.3 the pointerdown and pointerup events are unavailable. How to implement this in the latest version of openlayers?